# creating symbolic link to Dropbox on two different computers

Tags: dropbox

This is what I am hoping to do -- on computer A

```
computer A/~/Dropbox/folder@ -> /~/Documents/folder
```

and on computer B

```
computer B/~/Dropbox/folder@ -> /~/Documents/folder
```

That is, I want Dropbox/folder linking to external folders on both computers. My hope is that this way I will not only have ~/folder synchronized on both computers via Dropbox, I will also have the contents on the computer, in case I am disconnected from the net and can't reach Dropbox.

I am at a loss how to accomplish the above.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbolic Links to an Existing Folder](http://superuser.com/questions/370817/symbolic-links-to-an-existing-folder)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The symlink will be synchronized, but the actual directory and its contents will remain on each computer. You should do it the other way around, i.e. put the real content under `~/Dropbox/` and then symlink to it from outside.