# Symbolic Links to an Existing Folder

Tags: dropbox, symbolic-link

I'm trying to synchronize two folders on two different computers to my Dropbox folder on their respective machines. So for example:

**XP**:
C:\Dev -> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Dropbox\Dev

**OSX**:
~/dev -> ~/Dropbox/Dev

I'm using `junction` on XP and `ln` on OSX. However if I create the link using `junction` first, and that folder syncs via Dropbox to my Mac, I can't create the symbolic link there. And vice versa. Essentially I want the contents of these folders merged into Dropbox/Dev (so that they are **actually** merged in `C:\Dev` and `~/dev`) on both machines.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not how symlinks work.

Symlinks don't take two separate objects and turn them into one link. Rather they take one object and turn them into two separate links.

In your case, you need to turn the arrows the other way.

XP: Dropbox -> c:\Dev

OSX: Dropbox -> ~/Dev

That turn the Dropbox into the target of the symlink. So any changes you do to those files are really changes to the Dropbox files.

If you want the arrows the original way, then symlinks aren't the tool.  You'll need a folder merging tool that takes your local machine changes and merges them into the Dropbox folder.  That is more complicated and if they are source files, then I highly recommend you go with a Version Control Tool like Git or Mercurial.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. The way you suggested works great, and is exactly what I was looking for.